# How do you express the theorem statement about unsuccessful search on average-case for unsuccessful searches in hashing with quantifiers?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, terminology, data-structures, hash-tables, average-case

I was reading CLRS and in theorem 11.1 it states:

> In a hash table in which collisions are resolved by chaining, an unsuccessful search takes average-case time $\Theta( 1 + \alpha )$, under the assumption of [simple uniform hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_(computer_science)).

I was trying to understand how to express this theorem with quantifiers ($\exists, \forall$) and how it relates to "average-case" time (precisely, what they mean with average case time).

Is the theorem a statement that holds for all or any key? Or does it hold for all key on average and what does "on average" mean rigorously?

Usually, I like separating the terms expectation and average because the have different meanings. Expectation usually I think of it as the expected value of something according to some underlying distribution. For Average I think of the average value given a sample. So with these in mind, is the "average-case" scenario the same as the average running time for any key? i.e. Let $T_k$ denote the amount of time to search of a key $k$. This is a random quantity because it depends on the key we search for. Define the average-case runtime for any search to be $Search = \sum^n_{k=1} T_k$. Is the theorem statement in CLRS statement about the random variable $Search$ I just defined? (Which takes into account all keys at once and hence, applied for "any key" I guess). Or what do they mean by average-case precisely?

Comment: Are you asking what "average-case time" means?  If so, what research have you done?  This is a standard concept in algorithms.  What textbooks have you checked?

Comment: its not standard, algorithms are usually analyzed in worst-case. Thats standard. Average case can be when the algorithms have an input distribution, or even in amortized analysis is a different framework for "average case". Some people even confuse average with expectations. What I am saying is that I can't follow what CLRS says cuz they don't rigorously define what they mean by average case in exactly that chapter of CLRS page 258 chapter 11 nor do they have clear quantifiers for when their statements hold for searches. Maybe I'm dum cuz I can't tell when its not clearly stated.

Comment: Average-case analysis *is* totally standard: you just need to read the right textbooks.  I suggest you read a textbook on randomized algorithms, or a textbook that covers them.  For instance, *Randomized Algorithms* by Motwani and Raghavan is good, though might be a bit more advanced than what you're looking for.  Amortized analysis is different; average-case running time is about averaging over the internal random bits that the algorithm uses.

Comment: That maybe be the case for that book, but CLRS is the most standard book for algorithms and worst case analysis is obviously the most prominent one. Since those text books are more familiar for very specialized courses like randomized algorithms close, its no wonder I've not read them (though I've seen them advertised for those classes). Regardless, thats getting tangential. The point is I am not familiar with those books and CLRS didn't explicitly define in that chapter what they mean, hence, my confusion. But I do have good background in probability, so that isn't my problem.

Comment: You should do a significant amount of research before asking, and exhaust all reasonable resources.  I haven't checked whether CLRS has any coverage of this, but if CLRS doesn't have the answer, don't just give up.  There are lots of things CLRS won't have the answer to -- it's worth developing the ability to find other relevant resources!

Comment: @D.W. I did pretty good research and I know the terms. Also, my question is very specific to what CLRS writes. Anyway, I will try to re-phrase my question to make it clear what I've done before re-posting.

Comment: @CharlieParker CLRS is a nice book for some things, but it certainly does not tell the whole story of algorithm analysis. You might want to expand your horizon by checking out "An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" by Sedgewick and Flajolet. They focus on average-case analysis, for what I feel are better reasons than the one CLRS bring forth for their focus on WC.

Comment: @CharlieParker CLRS write explicitly (Section 2.2, p27f in 3rd ed) that they focus on worst-case. They also state that they will usually consider uniform input distributions, but their phrasings suggest that they will explain what they are doing when they are doing it.

Comment: You got elaborate answers. Changing the question completely is not nice. I suggest you roll back that big edit and post any follow-up questions you have as new posts.

Comment: @Raphael I unfortunately wrote a question with a lot of gaps I assumed the reader could fill & from the comments (& answers) I got,I think I made a wrong assumption (like SUHA). Now that I had time to fix it I did providing **exactly** the question details I wanted to ask in the first place.I will go back on my edits to honor the people that tried to help my first question (even though its not really as a meaningful question).

Comment: @Raphael it still really bothers me how there are some gaps on my question (assuming to known by the reader), can't we just keep some of the details I wrote earlier and put them at the end as an appendix or something? As it stands now, it seems I don't even know what averages or expectations are in the question or what are the sources of randomness are. Or just make a new question as an extension or something?

Comment: @CharlieParker I think you should post a new question. This here read as if you didn't know the fundamentals, so that was what the answers addressed. That you misrepresented your issue is not the fault of those who wrote answers.

Answer (score 3):

There are two prominent uses of the term "average" in algorithm analysis.

1. **Average-case** as a special case of expected costs

   Here, "average case" just means "expected case w.r.t. uniform distribution". Since we *usually* analyse with uniform inputs in mind (everything else is hard, and there's not much reason to prefer one distribution over the other in most cases).

   *Example:* the average-case running-time cost of sorting algorithms
   is often analyzed w.r.t uniformly-random permutations.
2. **Average cost** in the classic sense.

   When analyzing data structures, we can look at average costs across
   the contained elements *for a fixed instance* -- no probability 
   distribution here (well, you *could*...).
   That is, we may still have/want to consider a worst-, average- or 
   best-case instance.

   *Example:* Consider BSTs. The average search cost of a *given tree* is 
   the total cost for searching all contained elements (one after the other)
   divided by the number of contained elements. This is a classic quantity
   in AofA called [internal path length](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InternalPathLength.html).

**Note:** There are situations where average and expected do not usually mean the same thing. For instance, the expected (also: average-case) height of BSTs is in $O(\log n)$ but the average height is in $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$. That is because "expected" is implicitly (by tradition) meant w.r.t. uniformly-random permutations of insertion operations whereas "average" means the average over all BSTs of a given size. The two distributions are not the same, and apparently significantly so!

*Recommendation:* Whenever you use "expected" or "average-case", be very clear about which quantities are random w.r.t. which distribution.

---

The specific sentence you quote is indeed not clear if read in isolation -- if you ignore that CLRS specify exactly what "simple uniform hashing" means on the very same page.

There are two potentially random variables here: 1) the content of the hashtable itself, and 2) the key searched for. *Simple uniform hashing* is a simple way of specifying both.

1. We abstract from sequences of insertions¹ and just assume that every one of the $n$ elements we inserted independently hashed to each of the $m$ addresses with probability $1/m$.
2. We assume that the searched key hashes to each address with probabilty $1/m$.

That's how the proof works: our search hits each list with probability $1/m$ (cf 2), and they all have the same expected length of $n/m$ (via 1). Hence, the expected cost (under this specific model) for searching for $x$ *not* in the table is proportional to

$\qquad\displaystyle\begin{align*}
  T_u(x,n,m) &= 1 + \sum_{i=1}^m \operatorname{Pr}[h(x) = i] \cdot \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{length}(T[i])] \\
              &\overset{1,2}{=} 1 +\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{n}{m} \\
              &= 1 + \frac{n}{m}.
\end{align*}$

The "$+1$" is there to account for computing $h(x)$ and accessing $T[h(x)]$, the sum represents the cost for searching along the list.

---

1. That is fair since the sequence of insertions does not have as much impact on the resulting structure as for, say, BSTs. The hash function shakes everything up. We don't want to talk about the precise interaction of sequence and hash function, so we just assume that the result of both is independently uniform -- that's something we can work with. It may not represent reality, of course!

Comment: There are two sources of randomness, the keys and the lengths of the table. The lengths of the chains is clearly dependent on how the hash function spreads elements out randomly. However, the part that isn't 100% clear from your answer is how you took care of the distribution of which keys we searched for.  If $$E[T] = \sum^{n}_{i=1} E_{t \sim Pr[T]} [T_{h(k)}] Pr[Key = k]$$ is the expected time to search for any key, then, why can't you just simply conclude $E_{t \sim Pr[T]} [T_{h(k)}] \leq E_{n \sim Pr[N]} [n_{h(k)}]  =  \frac{n}{m}$ and just call everything done by pluging it in to $E[T] $?

Comment: See the two numbered list items. The simple uniform hashing assumption allows us to ignore the actual keys.

Comment: sorry if this is super easy/obvious to you. But how does that assumption make this possible? If you could write some details for this I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 2):

The average-case running time (or expected running time) of a randomized algorithm is typically defined to be the expectation of the running time of the algorithm, with respect to the random coins used by the algorithm (i.e., the random bits used internally in the algorithm).

If this number depends on the input, we often choose the worst case over all inputs.  If it matters, a good source should say what it means.

Note that this has nothing to do with amortized analysis.  Amortized running time is something completely different; it is about the running time of a *sequence* of operation, and applies equally well to deterministic algorithms, whereas average-case running time applies only to randomized algorithms.

---

Therefore, the statement you are quoting means: for all keys, the running time to search for a particular key is a random variable whose expectation is $\Theta(1+\alpha)$. (It's a random variable, because the running time depends on the randomness in the hash function.)

---

Caveat: You may occasionally find some situations where a particular distribution on the inputs is specified, and one takes the expectation of the running time with respect to the random choice of input.  However, this usage is rare and it would probably be poor form to use average-case for this meaning, if it's not clear from context that this is what was intended.

Comment: That is not how CLRS defines average-case running time.In fact they make the clear distinction btw the two in page 115 at the bottom & then in page 117 (defining the two). Average-case & expected runtime are different in CLRS. Maybe this is a confusing non-standard thing across different books.Regardless,unfortunately,I already knew your distinction and doesn't clarify the theorems 11.1/11.2 which Im trying to understand.I will try to think how to re-phrase my question to make it more clear.Apologies for that, let my try again to make it clear what I'm confused about. Though thnx for the help.